# Is there a way to create functions with different variable names depending on the number of arguments?

Tags: matlab

For example, `plot(Y)` and `plot(X,Y)` have fundamentally different signatures that both show up in the autocomplete menu when you start type `plot(`. I want to create a function that has two signatures: `foo(A,B)` and `foo(X, Y, Z)`. Is this possible without digging into all of the JSON documentation stuff?

Comment: You can use [varargin](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html) for vaiable number of input and [varargout](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargout.html) for variable number of output

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [carefully crafted help text](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/add-help-for-your-program.html) to achieve this:

```
function varargout = foo(varargin)
%FOO Foo
%  OUT=FOO(A,B) 2 arg version
%
%  OUT=FOO(X,Y,Z) 3 arg version
    varargout = {numel(varargin)};
end
```

(This has the same limitation as the functionSignatures.json though - the two options will only show up in the Live Editor - see https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/customize-code-suggestions-and-completions.html#mw_fe6f6fe5-bd10-4f61-9a60-8d570ab17f72 )